# Can you add a menu item to Photoshop with scripting?

Tags: photoshop-script

I've written a script that has a couple of functions for copy and paste.  I'd like to add a menu item (maybe under Edit) for both and link them to each respective function.  Is this even possible?  I'm using CS6 Javascript.  Thanks.

An example that shows how to create a menu item that calls a function containing an alert would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe so. Creating menu items requires you to create a plug-in with the Photoshop SDK. There are many examples that come with the included documentation.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I thought it might be a stretch for scripting and unless someone can show otherwise, we'll assume it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I've found to create a menu item.  That is, scripts placed in a particular folder will be automatically found on restart, and then you can create keyboard shortcuts allowing for quicker access.)

1. Add your script to the Preset folder (It'll be something like, `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2014\Presets\Scripts`)
2. Restart Photoshop and your preset will be listed with the other scripts in the (**File -> Scripts**) menu.
3. Add a keyboard shortcut to the menu item. In the (**Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts**) menu, expand the (File -> Scripts) tab and follow the instructions to add shortcuts.

Comment: Sadly is not reflecting changes in the script, imho. It remembers the script when Photoshop was started. But useful nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create menu items by using Adobe's Generator tool. See below link for more information.

https://github.com/adobe-photoshop/generator-core

```
_generator.addMenuItem(id, label, true, false).then(
    function () {
        console.log("menu item added:", label)
    }, function () {
        console.error("unable to add menu item", label)
    }
);
```